# how to change flowplayer video using jquery

Tags: jquery, flowplayer

This is my html

```
    <div data-engine="flash" data-swf="/template/styles/flowplayer.swf"
          class="flowplayer no-toggle is-splash minimalist"
          data-ratio="0.5625" data-embed="false">
          <video>
          <source type="video/mp4" src="/template/styles/movie.mp4">
          <source type="video/ogg" src="/template/styles/movie.ogv">

          </video>

       </div>
<button id="pat_edu">play another</button>
```

I want to change the video to some other video on click of a button. 
here is my script.

```
$('#pat_edu').click(function () {
    api.playClip({'url':'/template/styles/test.mp4', 'autoplay':true});
   });
```

It says the api is not defined.. 
in the headers i have added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/template/script/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file is correctly loaded ? Can you check that with the web inspector/firebug ?

Comment: Yes the file is loaded. I checked it.

Answer (score 1):

> It says the api is not defined..

That is because you have not used the flowplayer function to get a handle on the API.

**Example**

```
flowplayer(function(api, root)){
    api.load('/templates/styles/test.mp4');
}
```

I'm not sure there is a `playClip` method, but you should be able to use `load()` or `play()` instead.

All this info can be found on [flowplayer API docs](http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html)